# How to retrieve data for previous 12 months when monthly data is in columns by year?

Tags: sql, ms-access

i am working on a project which is having MS Access database. Its structure is something like:

```
some id
m1(stands for month 1 jan)
m2(stands for month 2 feb)
.
.
m12( stands for month 12 dec)
year
```

Now to retrieve data for this year i can write

```
Select * from tbl where id=123 and year=2016
```

But i don't want data of only one year. Suppose it is July now so i want data from Last june(2015) to June(2016). How can we do it? Right now i am finding results in two queries and then merging it using if else.

Comment: If _m1_ to _m12_ really are _field names_, you are in trouble, and you would need to create a union query to attempt some pseudo normalisation.

Comment: Yes they are. And that's why i am facing issue. :(

Comment: Ouch. But @Gord showed how to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me in Access 2010:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 1, 1) AS MonthStart, [m1] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 2, 1) AS MonthStart, [m2] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 3, 1) AS MonthStart, [m3] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 4, 1) AS MonthStart, [m4] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 5, 1) AS MonthStart, [m5] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 6, 1) AS MonthStart, [m6] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 7, 1) AS MonthStart, [m7] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 8, 1) AS MonthStart, [m8] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 9, 1) AS MonthStart, [m9] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 10, 1) AS MonthStart, [m10] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 11, 1) AS MonthStart, [m11] AS TheValue FROM tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DateSerial([year], 12, 1) AS MonthStart, [m12] AS TheValue FROM tbl
    )
WHERE 
    MonthStart 
        BETWEEN
            DateSerial(Year(Date()) - 1, Month(Date()), 1)
        AND
            DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1)
ORDER BY MonthStart
```

The UNION ALL subquery "unpivots" the data, and the WHERE clause isolates the results for the previous 12 months.

Comment: Not exactly what i required, but solved my problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Where (month in (6,7,8,9,10,11,12) and year=2015) or (month in (1,2,3,4,5,6) and year=2016) and ID=123
```

Edit: you can use

```
Where (month in (x to 12) and year=y) or (month in (1 to x) and year=y+1)
```

x being the number of month you want, y being starting year

2nd Edit: I don't know if `(x to y)` can be used in access so you better use

```
Where (month (Between x and 12) and year=y) or ((month Between 1 and x) and year=y+1)
```

Comment: but again this is static right?? it needs to be dynamic